# Meteor: How can I show questions only asked by users with the field 'active'

Tags: performance, mongodb, meteor

I am building a quora of sorts.. and I am trying to clean up my website. Currently if a user deletes their profile, their question remains there and will display no user. I am trying to link it up users.

What I did was I added a field on the users db that changes from 'active to 'inactive'(there is no deletion).

So my question is how can I query mongo so I can only show questions by users that have the 'active' tag on the users db.

I have no idea how to do a cross database query. Is this the right way to do it and if so how is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options, but the easiest is just to mark the questions as inactive as soon as their author becomes inactive. Here's an example `deleteUser` method:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  deleteUser: function() {
    // mark the user as inactive
    Meteor.users.update(this.userId, {$set: {isInactive: true}});

    // mark the user's questions as inactive
    Questions.update(
      {author: this.userId},
      {$set: {isInactive: true}},
      {multi: true}
    );
  }
});
```

Because the data about inactive authors has already been propagated to the `Questions` collection, your publish function could look something like this:

```js
Meteor.publish('activeQuestions', function() {
  // only return active posts
  return Questions.find({isInactive: {$ne: true}});
});
```